# Emacs Sunrise Commander only with name-size-time display

Tags: dired, sunrise-commander

Normally two-panes file managers display only three fields per file: the file name, the file size (possibly in human format) and the file modification time. See for example Midnight Commander:

[image: Midnight_Commander].

As for Emacs Sunrise Commander, we have a lot of info (user, owner, permissions), which  make it inconvenient on a laptop screen and perhaps distracting:

[image: Sunrise Commander]

How is is possible to get the standard 3-field layout with Sunrise Commander?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence to show only name, size and modification time is:

```
(setq sr-attributes-display-mask '(nil nil nil nil t t t))
(sr-toggle-attributes)
(sunrise)
```

The order is not the best one as the name is displayed last.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sr-attributes-display-mask` variable to control this. I think the following will do what you want:

```
(setq sr-attributes-display-mask '(nil nil nil nil t t t))
```

Comment: Unfortunately `(setq sr-attributes-display-mask '(nil nil nil nil t t t))` and after `(sunrise)` still gives a very long format in Sunrise (and dired too).